# Filestack-js: save square version, adding white space if needed

Tags: javascript, filestack

I'm using [Filestack-js](https://github.com/filestack/filestack-js) and I want users to upload an image with any aspect ratio, then have a squared version ready to use, not cropping the original but adding space if needed.

I've tried with the [crop options](https://filestack.github.io/filestack-js/interfaces/pickercropoptions.html) but it forces the user to select a square part of the image.

I've also tried with their [processing api](https://www.filestack.com/docs/api/processing/#resize) but doesn't return a square version either.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I also have this issue - did you happen upon a solution to this?